# Allow anyone to download any file from my computer

Tags: windows-7, download

I'm using Windows 7, and I want to make all of the files on my computer publicly accessible, so that anyone can download any of the files on my computer. Is there any way to do this without using an external web server (such as Dropbox)? I think I'd need to set up a local web server on my computer, but I'm not sure which type of server would be best suited to this task.

(Of course, this would be a very risky thing to do, unless it were done with a computer that had no sensitive information on it at all. I just want to know whether it would be possible.)

Comment: This wouldn't be a security concern if I didn't have any personally sensitive information on my hard drive. It would be useful to allow anyone to download any file from my computer at any time.

Comment: Oh, if you use this machine for *any* other use but a file server, than you have sensitive information on it, you just don't know it.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Yes, it would be very risky to do something like this, and would require extreme caution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely bad idea for a few reasons.

Security consideration is one of them. You might not realize what is sensitive and what is not..

This is essentially a software piracy. If you allow anybody to download any file from your computer, that includes files from Windows install, which are copyrighted by Microsoft and you are not allowed to distribute them. Similarly with any other software you have installed on that computer.

Yet if you still want to go ahead with this idea, you can use [HFS ~ Http File Server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) and share your whole C:\ from it.

Comment: In that case, it might be better to use a free operating system (such as Linux) for this purpose.

Comment: At first, it didn't occur to me that this might be considered software piracy. I hope I wouldn't be thrown in jail for sharing the contents of my hard disk online - that would be extremely unfair. :/

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't recommend it, you don't necessarily want a NAS but an sftp server. This is much safer than a public NAS. If you go this route, I do recommend giving out specific user accounts, and also only sharing out a specific folder. http://www.hosting.com/support/ftp/setting-up-filezilla-for-sftp

Answer (score 0):

Check out Opera Unite...ought be easier than setting up a NAS / file server

http://unite.opera.com/application/132/